# Fix broken jumper wire

Tags: wire, repair, jumper

Comes with the Arduino Uno

[image]

As you can see, it may require soldering. I don't have soldering experience but am receiving a soldering iron soon. Could you explain how this would need to be soldered if that's the case?

[image]

Comment: You don't fix these, you just buy more.

Comment: If you're using lots of these, it's not even worth it to buy new crimps to replace broken ones. It's more worth your time to have spares than to trim/strip/place/crimp a new connector pin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***You wouldnt. These are consumables that cost a fraction of a cent. You buy new ones for 20 or 50 for a dollar shipped.***

The pin on that is formed metal that is crimped on, it is not soldered. You could try soldering the pin back on, but it will be a task in futility.

Answer (score 0):

solder is not as strong as original unless crimped for strain relief.

Just use 22-24AWG solid jumper wire from phone cable cut and stripped to many short lengths for neater breadboard and lower inductance.

Comment: That's a pretty tough wire.. Fortunately, I discovered Fry's today and I almost fainted–it's paradise for electronic components. So I bought 50 wires for 10 bucks. Thanks for the help guys!      @Passerby